# Displaying stuff in a rich text box

Tags: c#, richtextbox, output

I'm trying to display the following in a rich text box. This is what I'm trying to display

**// The “Calculate” button calculates gross pay, taxes, and net pay and then                                                                                                 displays name, department, gross pay, taxes, and net pay using currency format for various         amounts in the rich text box**

These are declared at the beginning of the code:

```
      **private const decimal TAX = 0.25m;
      private string name="";**
```

This is the calculate button:

```
private void CalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
        // Gross pay=  (hours * rate)
        // Taxes= (25% of gross pay)
        // Net pay (gross pay ?taxes)
        decimal Gross_pay;
        decimal Taxes;
        decimal Net_Pay;
        decimal annual_salary;

        //calculate         


        Gross_pay = Convert.ToInt32(HoursTextBox.Text) * decimal.Parse(RateTextBox.Text);
        Taxes = TAX * Gross_pay;
        Net_Pay = Gross_pay - Taxes;

        annual_salary = Net_Pay;



        //display
        DisplayOutPut.Text = NameTextBox.Text;
        DisplayOutPut.Text = HoursTextBox.Text;
        DisplayOutPut.Text = RateTextBox.Text;
        DisplayOutPut.Text = Gross_pay.ToString("C"); // Hours*Rate
        DisplayOutPut.Text= Taxes.ToString("C");
        DisplayOutPut.Text= Net_Pay.ToString("C");
```

Comment: I figured out how to get the gross pay to display, as for the other ones, I'm working on it as well.

Comment: And what is not working? You only see the Net_Pay in the richtext box?

Comment: I only see gross pay and that's if I comment out the lines below it. If I don't comment them out I only get the numbers and not the "Gross Pay" text.

Comment: Change the ='s to += to append the text to DisplayOutput (but it will look messy). Take a look at StringBuilder and its AppendLine and Append methods for better formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) and add a [NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

```
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(NameTextBox.Text);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(HoursTextBox.Text);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(RateTextBox.Text);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Gross_pay.ToString("C")); // Hours*Rate
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Taxes.ToString("C"));
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    DisplayOutPut.AppendText(Net_Pay.ToString("C"));
```

Comment: Is this a better way to write it as opposed to using +=?

Comment: I assume the RichTextBox uses a StringBuilder or other advanced char buffer to appendtext. If you use += for sure the curent string is send to the garbage collector. (in this example 11 strings needs to be GC-ed if you use +=)